# Using a class with a template base class as a base class argument

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, vector, arguments

Am I missing something here? or is there a reason this is not allowed?

```
// the class declaration
class MapImage : public MapEntity, public Vector2D {};

// the variable declaration
std::vector<MapImage> healthpacks;

// the function
void DrawItems(SDL_Surface *dest, std::vector<Vector2D> &items, SDL_Surface *image);

// the implementation
DrawItems(dest, healthpacks, healthpack_image);
```

since healthpacks is a std::vector of MapImage classes, and MapImage has the base class Vector2D, shouldn't "std::vector healthpacks" be compatible with "std::vector &items" since they have the same base class?

Comment: Yes.  What compilation error do you get?

Comment: Use &lt; or backticks so your vector<Type> doesn't get misparsed (with <Type> becoming hidden) in the question text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A vector of a base class is not itself a base class of a vector of a derived class.

Consider if DrawItems inserted a Vector2D object, one which is *not* a MapImage, into items: you would have something that isn't a MapImage in a vector<MapImage>.  However, since DrawItems has a vector<Vector2D>, that insertion would be perfectly valid from its perspective.

Instead, pass an iterator range and template on the iterator:

```
void DrawItem(SDL_Surface *dest, Vector2D &item, SDL_Surface *image);

template<class Iter>
void DrawItems(SDL_Surface *dest, Iter begin, Iter end, SDL_Surface *image) {
  for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
    DrawItem(dest, *begin, image);
  }
}
```

Or on the container:

```
template<class Container>
void DrawItems(SDL_Surface *dest, Container &items, SDL_Surface *image) {
  typename Container::iterator begin = items.begin(), end = items.end();
  for (; begin != end; ++begin) {
    DrawItem(dest, *begin, image);
  }
}
```

Or, instead of DrawItems at all but still with DrawItem as I declared above, maybe use a new-fangled for-each loop:

```
// this: DrawItems(dest, healthpacks, healthpack_image);
// becomes:
for (auto &x : healthpack) DrawItem(dest, x, healthpack_image);
```

It also appears you need to add const, but I've left the code like you had it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, no.

Sure you can upcast from MapImage to Vector2D, but the vector<>'s are unrelated types. 
Are you expecting a direct case, or a copy to be created? The latter won't happen because of the non-const reference to the vector<>.

Why? Support these were just arrays, an iterator would need to know the size of a record, and this will be different for the different types.